# Always showing cookies error for a first time visitor trying to login

Tags: wordpress, authentication, cookies

I am using WPBrigade plugin "LoginPress" and has a login page which is created from file: `wp-login.php`.

If a new visitor is logging into the site, it displays an `login_error` with the following warning:

> quote **Error:** *Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies in order to use WordPress.*

If the user tries to login again without clicking on the link provided by the error message and do not adjust browser settings regarding cookies the login works fine and the user is logged into the site. If they click on the link they are redirected to wordpress official site regarding cookies. If they then return to the site it works fine (since it's a second attempt like in the first case).

My problem is that I want the user to be able to login without having this warning that disturbs the user experience. The login process is now 2 steps with a mandatory second try that works. I want it to work the first time. I can't seem to find the solution plugin documentation, and niether on wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

Check the issue by enabling the debugging in WordPress

https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/